# Post 403 forbidden on Yii2 Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, yii2

I know there's other topic on this in stackoverflow but it still didn't work for me. I try to make a simple dynamic menu that generate dynamic content based on the chosen `<li>` id.

This is the code to generate the menu :

```
foreach($cabang as $index=>$model){
 echo  '<li  id='.$model->idDpd->id_dpd.'>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'.$model->idDpd->dpd.'</a>
          </li>';

}
```

The menu is created successfully. But I have the problem with the content generated with Ajax

This is what I have in my view file :

```
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){

 function load_page_details(id)
 {
  $.ajax({

    url: "<?=Url::to(['/site/fetch']) ?>",
   method:"POST",
   data:{id:id}, //pass the 'id' of Load_page_details function parameter to the targeted URL
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#page_details').html(data);
   }
  });
 }

//load page-details where the id in the database table equals 1. Set the default to 1 while page is loading for the first time.
/* load_page_details(1);*/

 $('.nav li').click(function(){
  var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
  load_page_details(page_id);
 });


});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script)

?>
```

This is my SiteController and the action :

```
public function actionFetch(){

if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

// fetch the $_POST["id"]
 $data = Yii::$app->request->post('id');
if(isset($data)) 
{
$query= Cabang::find()->where(['id_dpd'=> $data])
        ->joinWith('idDpd')
        ->all();

 $output = '';
 foreach($query as $model)
 {
  $output .= '
   <div role="tabpanel" class="col-lg-4 tab-pane fade show active" >
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4>'.$model->kota.'</h4>
                    <p>'.$model->alamat.'</p>
                    <p>'.$model->telp.'</p>
                    <p>'.$model->email.'</p>
                    <p>'.$model->jadwal.'</p>
                  </div>
                 </div>
  ';
 }
/* echo $output;*/
 // return Json    
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($output);
}

}


}
```

The error caught in my console in chorome dev tool : `jquery.js:9175 POST http://localhost/%3C?=Url::to([%27/site/fetch%27])%20?%3E 403 (Forbidden)`

I tried to make the fetch function to a new php file and link the URL in my Ajax to that file (not to a controller or SiteController in my case) like :  url: `url:"site/fetch.php"`,but it returned `jquery.js:9175 POST http://localhost/site/fetch.php 404 (Not Found)`

What am I doing wrong? I have spent two days without solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP is not correct - you cannot use `<?= /* ... */ ?>` inside of heredoc. You need to use temporary variable:

```
$url = Url::to(['/site/fetch']);
$script = <<<JS
$(document).ready(function () {
    function load_page_details(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "$url",
            method: "POST",
            data: {id: id}, //pass the 'id' of Load_page_details function parameter to the targeted URL
            success: function (data) {
                $('#page_details').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    $('.nav li').click(function () {
        var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
        load_page_details(page_id);
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I changed that and get a different error in my console : `jquery.js:9175 POST http://localhost/site/fetch 500 (Internal Server Error)`

What caused this? I think my URL route is correct

Comment: Ah I find the problem. My query is wrong. It now works! Thanks!